# default maxsize for mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

Can anyone tell me what is the default mongodb database maxsize.
I have installed mongodb on my windows server, and created a document(db).
Document created and it is showing the size - 65,536KB. Is this max size that I
can write the data or can I extend it.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions. Please ask questions related to database administration on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb's manual shows as below:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

MongoDB Limits and Thresholds

This document provides a collection of hard and soft limitations of the MongoDB system.

BSON Documents

BSON Document Size
The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API. See mongofiles and the documentation for your driver for more information about GridFS.